# Where to place model classes in the Vuex project structure?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm working on a Vue app with Vuex state management using Type Script. I'm wondering where I should place my model classes. Currently I have them under "store" in a sub-directory "models". Now I have many more custom types used by the models and I'm not sure anymore whether the "store" directory is the right place. But on the other hand, the models are in a tight relationship with the state, right?

What is best-practice for this?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: put the "models" folder next to your "store" folder, not inside.

Long answer:

There are generally two strategies for organizing files:

1. Grouping by utility (eg. models, services, components etc.)
2. Grouping by domain category (eg. users, products, bookings etc.)

Whatever you choose there's a tradeoff.

The first strategy is most common. It prevents your project from getting many folders in your root folder, and it makes it easy to decide where to put new files. The drawback is that closely related files end up far apart, and as your codebase grows you will spend time looking for files that depend on each other.

The second keeps related files nicely together. Imagine for example a folder called Pets that contains a pet model, a pet component, a pet service and a unit test for that service. That makes navigating through Pet logic a lot easier. However, directories follow a tree structure while the domain model looks more like a graph and that can cause difficulties for properly organizing your files.

I find that people most often organize code by utility first, and by domain category second, but I'm not sure if I would call it best practice. The other way around has often worked out nicely for me as well.

If you organize by utility then you should avoid nesting them because it's almost never the case that one kind of utility uniquely belongs to another. Certainly models don't uniquely belong to a store. A component that depends on a model is just as tightly coupled to that model as a store. Therefore placing the "models" folder next to the "store" folder would make more sense.

Comment: Grouping by utility is much easier for a new developer to jump in your code and start contributing, while grouping by domain category requires them to first understand your application logic, and then start to contribute.

Comment: It's usually a good idea for a new developer to understand the application logic before contributing, at least basically. Grouping by domain turns out to be another way to self document your code.